# Do you know why it appears "Trying to get property of non-object"?

Tags: laravel

I want to show the conference start date if the start_date column in the conference table is not null, otherwise show '', so I have:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <p class="font-size-xsm"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    {{
    ($draftConference->conference->start_date) ?
    $draftConference->conference->start_dateformatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')
    : ''
    }}
    </p>
</li>
```

But it appears "Trying to get property of non-object" do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you firstly try get `$draftConference->conference->start_date` and then now checked it. But when `$draftConference->conference` is null that case happens your error. For fix it you must be use `!empty(...)` function or `isset(..)` . Try this fixed code

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <p class="font-size-xsm"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        {{!empthy($draftConference->conference->start_date) 
            ? $draftConference->conference->start_dateformatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')
            : ''
        }}
    </p>
</li>
```